# How do i remove roundcube deleted past mails without anybackup? I did just delete files on cpanel and they miss

Tags: webmail, roundcube

I guess im in trouble. I've got information above old site username and password. I did something but i dont know how to fix it. My customer wants new site. When i went cpanel i delete all files but files created like jung file. My custumer called me my old mails got lost accept todays. When he said that i understand what i did.

My question is i want to get back old mails to new roundcube files but i dont know where are they. Im not sure but i found some old files about roundcube db in etc file. If they are correct files where i have to put them? Thanks for everything from now :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0wDN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVHPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. We should find old **imap** file. When i creat new wordpress old imap folder name changed to imap1. Roundcube is reading imap folder. Just i changed names. Old folder imap1 to imap and other folder imap to imap 2. Then we got all mails back accept todays :) I think i can do copy new files to old one. I should i can see todays too .

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP3pU.png)